# How to keep a host using cPanel from sending the wrong ssl certificate

Tags: cpanel

This appears to be a cPanel problem. The good folks at name.com use cPanel. Hosting at name.com for my site is a problem in that when someone accesses my site with https the SSL certificate from another site is sent by the server.  cPanel docs seem to imply what I'm describing is a known problem. http requests are fine. Short of implementing SSL for my site, are there recommended ways to set up my site?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming because you dont have private SSL for your domain, so install a SSL for domain. 
You can get a free SSL from these 2 site:

https://www.startssl.com/

https://letsencrypt.org/

and request your hosting provider to install a SSL after that your website will on both `http://` and `https://`